How to Linearize the Product of Two Continuous Variables with Known Bounds in GAMS MILP Model
I have a Mixed-Integer Linear Programming (MILP) problem in GAMS where I need to linearize a bilinear term involving two variables. Specifically, I have the following equation:
$$
\text{eh17}(m,n,t) : \quad F_{ov}(m,n,t) = e = h_0(m,n,t) \cdot \left(\frac{II(m,n,t)}{II_{\text{max}}}\right)
$$
where $ h_0(m,n,t) $ is a variable between 0.001 and 0.3, $ II(m,n,t) $ is a variable between 0 and 0.14, and $ II_{\text{max}} $ is a constant scalar.
Could someone provide guidance on how to linearize this bilinear term in GAMS? What approach can be used to approximate this product with linear constraints?

You don't have a Mixed-Integer Linear Programming (MILP) problem in GAMS. You appear to have a Mixed-Integer Bilinear Programming problem. So use a Mixed-Integer Bilinear capable solver, and let it (adaptively) handle the bilinear term better than you could (statically) do yourself.

Thanks @MarkL.Stone. Do you recommend any special solver for this case?

Gurobi, or a general mixed-integer nonlinear global optimization solver.

Thank you very much.
